# change dyntopo mesh color away from white WITHOUT matcaps?

Tags: sculpt

WITHOUT changing the viewport shading or using matcaps (which darken the rest of the scene so colors do not match the current sculpt object's color), I need to change the dyntopo color of an object to make it dark green like grass, to aid in sculpting. Since every other color in blender is customizable, I assume this one is, too, and that I just cannot find the correct setting.
Land color is white instead of green while sculpting.
[image: Land color is white instead of green while sculpting.]
Turning on a dark green matcap makes the current sculpt look great but darkens everything else, making it a bad option.

[image: Turning on a dark green matcap makes the current sculpt look great but darkens everything else, making it a bad option.]

I just want to be able to select a solid color for the current dyntopo. it would not make sense to be forced to use white all the time so can anyone tell me where to change this default solid color?